# Launch application using openwith on mouse click

Tags: objective-c

Can any one tell me about how to lanch a self-made application using the "openwith" feature of a mouse click event?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear, but I understand it as "How do I tell the Finder that my application knows handle certain file types?". Once the Finder knows the link, it will suggest your application in the Open With submenu that appears when you ctrl/right-click on a file.

Have a look at the [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Documents/Concepts/DocTypePList.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000024-BHADAGHF). Basically, you have to declare all the supported file types in Info.plist (or what you called it). The system is based on [Universal Type Identifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_intro/understand_utis_intro.html).